# Why is an Empty Set, as in {}, a subset of all sets? (Java)

Tags: java, set, compare, hashset

So I have a quick question regarding sets.

I recently discovered while coding that no matter what I compare an empty set of mine to (using the `containsAll` method), the method will always return `true`. I'm curious... how come, even though my sets contain no empty slots (for example, `{1, 3, 5, , 9}`) every time I compare an empty set to ANY other set, it always returns `true`?

Also, how come `null`s don't do this? I understand that `null` statements are objects too within Java, but it's still a signification of "nothing" or "empty/void"

See my code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Set<Object> tester = new HashSet<Object>();
        Set<Object> data1 = new HashSet<Object>();
        Set<Object> dataNull = new HashSet<Object>();

        tester.add(1);  //Adding some random stuff
        tester.add(10);
        tester.add(0);
        dataNull.add(null);

        System.out.println(tester.containsAll(data1));
        System.out.println(tester.containsAll(dataNull));
    }
}
```

When executed, the output here is:

```
true
false
```

When asking if the tester contains all elements of the empty set, we get true. When asking if the tester contains all elements of the set ONLY CONTAINING A `null`, we get false.

Any explanations?

Thanks a ton!
~Andrew M

Comment: Because there is no element in the empty set which is not contained in all other sets.

Comment: What about the set of all sets that are not members of themselves, does it contain itself? ;)

Comment: Null is not an object. Null != empty. A null reference points to no object. An empty set has zero members. By definition, the empty set is a subset of all sets.

Comment: I guess I've misunderstood `null` statements! Thanks Andy, and thanks to everyone for the clear answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wikipedia definition of subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset#Definitions):

> If A and B are sets and every element of A is also an element of B, then:
>
> - A is a subset of (or is included in) B

Stated another way, A is a subset of B iff there is no element in A which is not also in B.

If A is the empty set, then there is no element in A which is not also in B, so the empty set is always a subset of B.

Comment: Ah i see how it looks at it now, I guess I was looking at it too straightforward. This makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

> When asking if the tester contains all elements of the empty set, we get true.

Because every set contains all the elements of the empty set, since the empty set has no elements.

> When asking if the tester contains all elements of the set ONLY CONTAINING A null, we get false.

Because the set does not contain a null element, thus it doesn't contain all the elements of the set.